# Remove the "Products tagged" from Woocommerce Tag Archive Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs, storefront

In my Storefront wordpress I'm using the woocommerce product tags to display my products in an alternative way. 
On the tag archive pages the breadcrumb says

Home > Products tagged “Example Tag”  or rather Startseite > Produkte verschlagwortet mit „Example Tag“ since I have a German language site.

-> I want to get rid of the "Products tagged" ("Produkte verschlagwortet mit") and have the Example Tag (without the quotation marks) only displayed in the Breadcrumb:

Home > Example Tag  ( Startseite > Example Tag)

I found a lot of stuff how to customize the breadcrumb in general, but nowhere how to red rid of that specific problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while, but it may help someone else.
I've come up with this:

```
/**
 * Remove "Products tagged" from product tags breadcrumbs
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'woocommerce_breadcrumbs_remove_text', 10);
function woocommerce_breadcrumbs_remove_text($crumbs) {

  // Check if we are in a product tag archive page
  if (is_product_tag()) {

    // Point to the last element of the breadcrumbs array, specifically the breadcrumb we are going to edit
    end($crumbs);

    // Get the text to edit (array key number 0)
    $last    = $crumbs[key($crumbs)][0];

    // Perform a regular expression to keep only what's between quotes (&ldquo; and &rdquo;)
    $replace = preg_replace('/[\s\S]+\&ldquo;([\s\S]+)\&rdquo;/', '$1', $last);

    // Register the new text to the breadcrumb array
    $crumbs[key($crumbs)][0] = $replace;

    // Reset the array pointer
    reset($crumbs);
  }

  // Return the filtered breadcrumbs array
  return $crumbs;
}
```

This is a filter using the `woocommerce_get_breadcrumb` hook. You should put this code into your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but try this:

```
// Customize text strings
function my_gettext( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translation ) {
        case 'Products tagged &ldquo;%s&rdquo;' :
            $translation = __( '%s', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_gettext', 20, 3 );
```

If you're using a ThemeBlvd theme, do this instead:

```
// Customize "Products tagged" in breadcrumbs
function my_locals( $locals ) {
    $locals['crumb_tag_products'] = '%s';
    return $locals;
}
add_filter('themeblvd_frontend_locals', 'my_locals');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select that item from Inspect Element and write custom CSS for it and set it to 
`display: none;`

Comment: No, since the text is in one Element and I want to keep a part (Example) of it visible 

<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb"><a href="http://example.com">Startseite</a><span class="breadcrumb-separator"> / </span>Produkte verschlagwortet mit „Example“</nav>

--> And that Tag is changing, so I caan't replace it with CSS

Answer (score 0):

This code works to removed Products tagged for English text Breadcrumb :

```
// Customize text strings
function my_gettext( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translation ) {
        case 'Products tagged &ldquo;%s&rdquo;' :
            $translation = __( '%s', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_gettext', 20, 3 );
```

But you can try this for French or other language than English :

```
///// Woocommerce : Remove "Products tagged" from product tags breadcrumbs FR
    
    function my_gettext( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
        if ( strpos( $text, 'Products tagged' ) !== false ) {
            $translation = '%s';
        }
    
        return $translation;
    }
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_gettext', 100, 3 );
```